# EF WillCascadeOnUpdate

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Is there a way in ef migrations to set the Foreign GUID key to cascade on update?
If I have two db's with a user table and the same user with different primary keys, I would like to set the primary GUID key of one to the other.

Basically I'm trying to avoid having to create another column between them to check for syncing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in this to solve:

1. How do get desired behaviour of the database and/or code.
2. How to get EF Migrations to generate the stuff needed (triggers or whatever) for the solution from point 1.

For the first part, I would look into using a trigger. For the second part, creating the trigger with migrations, it can be done by running a raw sql command in the migration step (you have to use a code based migration).